# concave rectangle with transparent gradient

Tags: html, css

I need a simple button with a color gradient and a transparent gradient layover faking a light glare. In the old days I created just the button with color gradient *(red to dark red)* and set a layer with a transparent gradient *(white, with opacity 0.25 to 0.50)* over the button.

**Like this Button:**
[image: concave rectangle with transparent gradient]

**But I have big problem with a concave horizon line:**
[image: concave rectangle with transparent gradient]

I marked it here with a theoretically line, just for better understanding.

**Tryout code on fiddle:**
I've been experimenting a bit with concave background settings here. But then I get no transparent history.

```css
#wrapper {
  background: grey;
  padding: 25px;
}

#test {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #888888;
    background:
      radial-gradient(circle 400px at 50% 266%, rgba(0,0,250,0.1), rgba(0,0,250,0.1) 100%, red 100%);
    background-size:200px 200px, 200px 200px;
    background-position:0 0,0 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="test">B1</div>
  <div id="test">B2</div>
</div>
```

But my CSS 2 skills are totally outdated.
Hence the question of whether there is a better solution for my financial button.

Does anyone have an idea how I can create such a button *(like the red one in the first picture)*? There may now be much more modern and simpler solutions. - It is important that the horizon line is **concave** *(laterally downwards)* and not convex *(ellipse downwards in the middle)*. Exactly as shown in the graphic.

I have to deal a lot more with CSS-3 and the latest technologies to improve my skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overlay multiple gradients, one on top of the other. I've used a transparent circular radial gradient to fade out the button with an edge then put a linear gradient below it. You can then use CSS custom properties to set the button colour to whatever you like. Code below. Twiddle about with the opacity values in the rgba() property to get the effect you're looking for.

**Edited** as the radius can't be a percentage value, I've used a custom property so that the button radius scales with the button size so you can use buttons of different widths and it'll scale up okay.

```css
#wrapper {
  background: grey;
  padding: 25px;
}

.button {
    display: inline-grid;
    place-items:center;
    --width:200px;
    width: var(--width);
    aspect-ratio:1/1;
    margin-right: 25px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    --button-colour: blue;
    background:
      radial-gradient(
        circle calc(var(--width) * 4) at 50% 270%,
        transparent 50%,
        rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 50%,
        rgba(255,255,255,1) 75%),
      linear-gradient(
        var(--button-colour),
        var(--button-colour)
      );
}

.red {
  --button-colour:red;
}

.green {
  --button-colour:green;
}

.blue {
  --button-colour:blue;
}

.small {
 --width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class='red button'>Red</div>
  <div class='green button'>Green</div>
  <div class='blue button'>Blue</div>
  <div class='small blue button'>Blue</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is also right. And I like using the variables. And using a radial and a linear gradient is a very clean solution. Especially since it can be dynamically reduced thanks to the percentage values and the circle ... without having to adjust the positions. This is perfect! Think I will use exactly that way. Thx Adam!

Comment: Nice one @Adam. Good solution 

Comment: Cheers Dan. :-)

Comment: And very important is the `aspect-ratio:1/1;` which I never saw before in a boxed element and it's working in all modern browsers. - I totally like it and the circle position, too. I add a dark color for the linear gradient. Maybe there is also a way to use `filter: brightness(75%);`, but it's working better with a second color, so I can fine-tune it. 

My version: https://jsfiddle.net/89bf3xd0/7/

Comment: Looks good. I think you have a better eye for shading that I have. I'm sure my eyeballs were only fitted with EGA graphics hardware :-D

Comment: That was the year I was born, so maybe I can also see only 16 colors. :P 5yrs before I was developing with C#-Core.NET web backends and sometimes with frontends, too. But the last 5yrs I'm just developing C#.NET desktop software with an old form-based windows app for ERP. And that's why I lost the focus to frontend techologies, like HTML, CSS, JS, ... But now ChatGPT awakes so I try to play a little bit with some sandbox projects and ai contents. And I have a chance to find back to the web stuff, again. If any of these projects turn a profit, I'll have to struggle with CSS or JS more often. :)

Comment: @Froschkoenig84 my first job out of college was programming the physics system for a game engine that ran on PS2, PSP, Wii, and PC. Oddly I find web development so much more satisfying. I still make games in JavaScript for fun.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this with one element and a radial gradient.

```css
button {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 150px, #B31609, #D5000C 69%, #DD3C3F 50%, #F0A696 100%);
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you Dan. You're totally right to set all colors in one `radial-gradient()`. I changed a little bit, but this is very good now: https://jsfiddle.net/89bf3xd0/6/ - So I learned from Dan that I can add as many colors as I want and indicate their position. In this way it was possible to use the third and fourth entry for the gradient at the bottom. - I hope that everyone else who has this problem can learn a lot from this.